# TestCafe: Clicking SSL link does not load page

Tags: hyperlink, ssl-certificate, e2e-testing, testcafe, clicking

In a test, I click a link (SSL Cert) link that does not actually load the expected URL page. It hangs and as far as I can tell no issues when I look at network or console. Is there a known issue with TestCafe and clicking certain kinds of links. Clicking the same link with Selenium and Robot Framework successfully takes you to the expected URL.

Answer (score 2):

This information is not sufficient to reproduce the problem. Please create a separate issue in the TestCafe Github repository using the following [form](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md)

I would appreciate it if you provide us with your project or url to your site and your test code. It will help us determine the cause of the issue efficiently.